# Multiple two-dimensional plots in 3D visualization

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, graphics3d, legending

How can I produce this kind of plot?
Please help[image: transmission vs detuning for different force values]

Comment: If the objective is to confuse or obfuscate, then go for it. If the objective is to inform, then a single 2D plot with all curves is what you want.

Answer (score 6):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{x, 1, Sin[x]}, {x, 2, Cos[x]}, {x, 3, 
   Sin[x^2]}}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.....But how can the gridlines be included? Parametric3D Plot doesn't support Gridlines

Comment: @Sohail it is helpful to include such a request when asking the original question. I’d suggest you update your question to reflect the additional inquiry . While the body of your post does imply this, the title of your post does not touch upon this. That being said, does not the post here have such gridlines? It seems so to me. To more explicitly control them, I would advise that you first determine the bounds of your 3D plotted region, then define the collection of gridlines you wish to show in your plot. This would be built in `Graphics3D` rather than using `ParametricPlot3D` as shown here.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot.